helm install with http-snippet returns 'invalid number of the map parameters in /tmp/nginx/nginx-cfg
I am running a .sh script :
helm install ...
--set controller.config.http-snippet='map $upstream_http_cache_control $custom_cache_control { '' "no-store"; } add_header Cache-Control $custom_cache_control;'
...
It returns the error message:
invalid number of the map parameters in /tmp/nginx/nginx-conf17...
any ideas?

Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In particular, what part of your Helm chart uses that .Values.controller... value?  The helm install --set option has a...unique syntax, and you may need to use --set-string, or to pass an additional -f YAML or JSON values file instead of trying to use the command line.
